# Python3 calling Python2 multiprocessing in Linux acts differently than in Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, multiprocessing, subprocess

I have a simple sample code running in `Python3.8`, that opens a `subprocess` that executes in `Python2.7` (utilizing multiprocessing).

In `Windows 10`, the behavior of my code is what my intention is.  Where the Python2 pool runs and prints to `stdout` accordingly.  And the `main.py` reads the stdout almost instantenously, as the pool writes on it.

Unfortunately, I am seeing different results with Linux (`Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`).  It seems, in Linux, I wont get anything back until the whole pool is completed.

How can I make the code work the same in Linux as well?

Please see simple sample code below and output I am getting.

Main.py

```
import subprocess
import datetime
import tempfile
import os

def get_time():
    return datetime.datetime.now()

class ProcReader():
    def __init__(self, python_file, temp=None, wait=False):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(['python2', python_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            line = self.proc.stdout.readline()
            if not line:
                raise StopIteration
            return line

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r1 = ProcReader("p2.py")

    for l1 in r1:
        print("Main reading at: {} for {}".format(get_time(), l1))
```

p2.py

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
import datetime

def get_time():
    return datetime.datetime.now()

def f1(name):
    for x in range(2):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("{} Job#: {} from f1".format(get_time(), name))

def f2(name):
    for x in range(2):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("{} Job#: {} from f2".format(get_time(), name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()

    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    tasks = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
    for i, task in enumerate(tasks):
        if i%2:
            pool.apply_async(f2, args=(task,))
        else:
            pool.apply_async(f1, args=(task,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Output for Windows:

```
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:19.044626 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:19.044000 Job#: 1 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:20.045454 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:20.045000 Job#: 1 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:20.046711 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:20.046000 Job#: 2 from f2\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:21.045510 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:21.045000 Job#: 3 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:22.046334 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:22.046000 Job#: 3 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:22.047368 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:22.047000 Job#: 2 from f2\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:23.047519 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:23.047000 Job#: 5 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:24.046356 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:24.046000 Job#: 4 from f2\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:24.048356 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:24.048000 Job#: 5 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:26.047307 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:26.047000 Job#: 4 from f2\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:26.049168 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:26.049000 Job#: 6 from f2\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:27.047897 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:27.047000 Job#: 7 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:28.048337 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:28.048000 Job#: 7 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 15:28:28.049367 for b'2020-09-24 15:28:28.049000 Job#: 6 from f2\n'
```

Output for Linux:

```
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.972346 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:36.932473 Job#: 1 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.972559 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:37.933594 Job#: 1 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.972585 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:38.935255 Job#: 3 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.972597 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:39.936297 Job#: 3 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.972685 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:40.937666 Job#: 5 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.972711 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:41.938629 Job#: 5 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.972724 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:43.941109 Job#: 6 from f2\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.972735 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:45.943310 Job#: 6 from f2\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.973115 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:37.933317 Job#: 2 from f2\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.973139 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:39.935938 Job#: 2 from f2\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.973149 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:41.938587 Job#: 4 from f2\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.973157 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:43.941109 Job#: 4 from f2\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.973165 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:44.942306 Job#: 7 from f1\n'
Main reading at: 2020-09-24 19:28:45.973173 for b'2020-09-24 19:28:45.943503 Job#: 7 from f1\n'
```

Please disregard the time since the clocks are different, but as you can see, in Windows `main.py` gets it as soon as it was written in python2 pool, but for `linux` everything in `main.py` is written only when all jobs were completed.  I am not too concerned about the order of the jobs being completed, I really just want `main.py` to get the `stdout` as soon as it is written in Python2 pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout` on Linux is buffered and `print()` on multiprocessing is not flushed because process not controls terminal.

Monkey patch of sys.stdout is useful here

```
import sys,os
unbuffered = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
sys.stdout = unbuffered
```

Or you might have to call `sys.stdout.flush()` after every `print()`